# NameError in a Discord Bot

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, discord

I have an error when I try to set up this. When I run it appear this error. What can I do? *the code is [here](https://github.com/DevilGale/PokeCord)* The error say:

```
File "C:\Users\meganano202\Desktop\PokeCord-master\var_secrets.py", line 4, in <module>
CLIENT_SECRET = yWW55ovf6-KxETrB1v18x_-QLUJaoaam #Discord given
NameError: name 'yWW55ovf6' is not defined
```

I tried changing the key but always say that the key is not defined

[I changed the secret key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO2hR.png)

```
from var_secrets import *

import os
import json
import pickle
import random
import asyncio

# api #
import discord
from imgurpython import ImgurClient

# DISCORD  VARS #
#client = discord.Client()

BOT_PREFIX = ";"
CHANNEL_IDs  = ("449281327988998156")

# PYTHON VALS #
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

# Globals #

imgr_client = ImgurClient(imgr_client_id, imgr_client_secret)

# Image Vars #
white = (255,255,255,255)
black = (0, 0, 0, 255)
```

and this code open this to get the information:

```
MASTER_ID = None #Discord ID

CLIENT_ID = None #Discord given
CLIENT_SECRET = None #Discord given
TOKEN = None #Discord given

imgr_client_id = None #IMGR Given
imgr_client_secret = None #IMGR Given
```

Comment: When you run what?  You haven't posted any code.

Comment: The value should be inside quotes.  `CLIENT_SECRET = "some value here"`

Comment: @Scott Hunter the code is posted in the github, is very long because there are more than 1 file

Comment: @Scott Hunter I added more code. Sorry I'm new here

Answer (score 1):

As @John Gordon mentioned

In `var_secrets.py` file you need put to put quotes around values

```py
CLIENT_SECRET = "yWW55ovf6-KxETrB1v18x_-QLUJaoaam".
```